# Scala turn map [String, List[Int, Double]] to [Int, List[String, Double]]

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, swap

I am struggling with a special mapping of a list.
It's propably easier for you to understand my problem if I show you a concrete instance directly:

How do I transform

```
(cat, List((0, 45.42), (1, 12.45), (2, 91.45))
(dog, List((0, 23.31), (1, 10.23), (2, 52.25))
```

to

```
(0, List((cat, 45.42)), List((dog, 23.31))
(1, List((cat, 12.45)), List((dog, 10.23))
(2, List((cat, 91.45)), List((dog, 52.25)))
```

the types are basically:

```
[(String, List[(Int, Double)])]
```

to

```
[(Int, List[(String, Double)])]
```

Is it possible to perform such operation using the chained functional programming functions of Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's the most beautiful idiomatic solutions, but it works

```
  val original: Map[String, List[(Int, Double)]] = Map(
    "cat" -> List((0, 45.42), (1, 12.45), (2, 91.45)),
    "dog" -> List((0, 23.31), (1, 10.23), (2, 52.25))
  )

  val flatten = for {
    (s, v) <- original
    (i, d) <- v
  } yield (i, s, d)

  implicit class RichTuple2[A, B, C](t: (A, B, C)) {
    def tail: (B, C) = (t._2, t._3)
  }

  val converted = flatten
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_.tail))

  println(converted)
```

Comment: if you group as `yield (i, (s, d))` you won't need `tail`

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
scala> val ori: Map[String, List[(Int, Double)]] = Map(
     |   "cat" -> List((0, 45.42), (1, 12.45), (2, 91.45)),
     |   "dog" -> List((0, 23.31), (1, 10.23), (2, 52.25))
     | )
ori: Map[String,List[(Int, Double)]] = Map(cat -> List((0,45.42), (1,12.45), (2,91.45)), dog -> List((0,23.31), (1,10.23), (2,52.25)))

scala> ori.foldLeft(Map[Int, List[(String, Double)]]()){ case (m, (k, v)) =>
     |   v.foldLeft(m){ case(r, (i, d)) => r.updated(i, r.getOrElse(i, Nil) :+ (k, d)) }
     | }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(String, Double)]] = Map(
       0 -> List((cat,45.42), (dog,23.31)), 
       1 -> List((cat,12.45), (dog,10.23)), 
       2 -> List((cat,91.45), (dog,52.25)))
```